# Cómo implemento éste fragmento de código en mi navbar?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código que encontré en `Bootstrap` para una **navbar**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Nutri Food</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menús <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Clásico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Light</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bajo en sodio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rico en fibras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Veggie</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">¿Cómo funciona?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Crear cuenta</button></li>
        <li><button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Iniciar sesión</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Y deseo implementar éste otro fragmento de código de mi actual navbar:

```
        <!--=====================================
        LOGOTIPO
        ======================================-->

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" id="logotipo">
            <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">  
                <img src="<?php echo $servidor.$social["logo"]; ?>" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
```

El problema es que cuando coloco el framento de código del logotipo, en la sección del navbar-brand, el resultado es el ícono de una imagen rota, como si no trajera nada de la base de datos.

¿Alguien me puede decir por qué, y cómo puedo solucionarlo para que aparezca la imagen del logotipo correctamente?

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Si ves una imagen rota entonces el link está mal o la ruta donde supuestamente tienes la imagen es incorrecta.

Utiliza el inspector de Google, dando click derecho en la imagen y podrás ver la ruta, revisa que sea la correcta y modifica tu **echo** de acuerdo a la que debería ser la ruta correcta.

Comment: Claro! El problema es que la ruta es correcta, y no se porqué aparece como imagen rota